# C# System.Forms.label

Tags: c#, winforms

I am dynamically displaying array of labels on a form and am getting a new set of labels to be displayed on the form when a function is called again. But instead, the previous labels are still on the screen with the new labels. How do I clear the previous set of labels on the form?

Thanks

Comment: How about just changing the text in the existing labels? What's different about the new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the old labels from the Form's "Controls" collection.  Is this a good idea/design?  Not so sure, but without seeing any code this is the best advice I can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500(VS.71).aspx) on "Implementing a Remove Method".  You need Controls.Remove.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the first set of labels to your form's Controls collection, also add them to a form-level List (call it "_labels" or something).  When you want to remove this first set from the form, do something like this:

```
foreach (Label l in _labels)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(l);
}
_labels.Clear();
```

Or if the only controls you have on the form are labels, you can remove them more simply:

```
this.Controls.Clear();
```